# Busqueda de XLSX Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, xlrd

Con este codigo logre convertir una determinada columna de un xlsx en lista. Ando necesitando una funcion que busque en el directorio donde estoy si hay algun archivo con los valores que hay en mi lista llamada a:

```
>>> [u'Jose', u'Martin', u'Pedro']
print jose
>>> Jose.xlsx
print martin
>>> Martin.xlsx
print pedro
>>> Pedro.xlsx
```

Como dije antes, necesito que busque en la carpeta donde estoy si hay algun archivo que se llame Jose, Martin y Pedro

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

file_name = 'Today.xlsx'

xl_file = pd.ExcelFile(file_name)

dfs = {sheet_name: xl_file.parse(sheet_name) 
          for sheet_name in xl_file.sheet_names}

a = dfs['Hoja1']['Cliente'] 

a = a.tolist()

jose = a[0]
jose =str(jose) + '{}'.format(file_type)

martin = a[1]
martin =str(martin) + '{}'.format(file_type)

pedro = a[2]
pedro =str(pedro) + '{}'.format(file_type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Este código devuelve todos los archivos que coinciden con los nombres que están en la lista llamada buscar.

```
import sys, os
# lista de diferentes nombres a buscar 
buscar = ["jose", "pedro", "juan"]
# directorio en el cual se ejecuta el script
directorio = os.getcwd()
# lleva la cuenta de la cantidad de archivos
total = 0

for root, dir, ficheros in os.walk(directorio):
    # iteramos en la lista de archivos del directorio
    for fichero in ficheros:
        # iteramos en la lista con los nombres que estamos buscando
        for nombre in buscar:
            # verificamos si de los nombres  que tenemos en la lista coinciden con los nombres de los archivos
            if(nombre in fichero.lower()):
                print(root+"\\"+fichero)
                total += 1

print("En total hay",total," archivos con",buscar)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si solo quieres buscar en el directorio en el que estás y no en sus subdirectorios, discriminar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas en el nombre y solo validar una determinada extensión, puedes usar simplemente `os.path.isfile`.

```
import os

a = [u'Jose', u'Martin', u'Pedro']
file_type = ".xlsx"

files = {name + file_type for name in a}
existing_files = {file for file in files if os.path.isfile(file)}
nonexistent_files = files - existing_files
```

Si por ejemplo solo existe `Martin.xlsx` en tu directorio la salida es:

```
>>> existing_filesu
{u'Martin.xlsx'}

>>> nonexistent_files
{u'Pedro.xlsx', u'Jose.xlsx'}
```